# Difference betwen .is family and .cd in pgfkeys in the context of package writing?

Tags: packages, programming, pgfkeys, package-writing, pgfopts

I am using `pgfopts` to create my own packages and handle options. `.family` and `.cd` can be used to group the package options together, but I am not sure to understand the pros and cons of each approach, and in which specific case I would use one rather than the other.

**QUESTION:** More specifically, what are the practical differences between the three following approaches, and in which case it would be better (or worse) to use one rather than the other two?

**[Approach 1] .family**

```
\pgfkeys{
    /mypackage/.is family,
    /mypackage,
    myoption/.store in = \mypackage@myoption,
    myoption = ,
}
```

**[Approach 2] .cd**

```
\pgfkeys{
    /mypackage/.cd,
    myoption/.store in = \mypackage@myoption,
    myoption = ,
}
```

**[Approach 3] .family and .cd** *(not sure it's possible)*

```
\pgfkeys{
    /mypackage/.is family,
    /mypackage/.cd,
    myoption/.store in = \mypackage@myoption,
    myoption = ,
}
```

*Note:* I am essentially looking for an explanation/clarification.

Comment: I wouldn't use pgfopts (or some other external package) for package options. That only adds an extra layer without much gain as key-val options are now in-built in LaTeX (and offer additional options to avoid option clash errors).

Comment: The only advantage of the `.is family` handler is to create your own command like `\tikzset` for setting options. This is recommended as it enables you to have late options. For package options I will take @UlrikeFischer advice the l3 layer is a better option.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just asked this question : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/709928/17200 to help me move from `pgfopts` to `latex3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems **pgfopts** uses the package **pgfkeys**, which in turn is a component of the TikT/PGF-bundle, whereof [pgfmanual.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) is the manual and reference. **pgfkeys** is described in "Part VII Utilities", chapter "87 Key Management".

A ⟨key⟩ of a ⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pair in the argument of the macro `\pgfkeys` consists of two components:
⟨key-path⟩ and ⟨key-name⟩.

The `/.cd`-handler lets you abbreviate so that in case of just providing ⟨key-name⟩, the ⟨key⟩ is completed by adding the ⟨key-path⟩ specified via the `/.cd`-thingie.

The key-handler `/.is family` does two things which I suggest to take for two concepts that are independent from each other.

**Thing 1:**

`/SomeFamilys/Path/.is family,` defines the key `/SomeFamilys/Path` to take no value and to do the same as `/SomeFamilys/Path/.cd`.

This is the way in which `/.is family` is used in your examples.

After doing `/SomeFamilys/Path/.is family,`, you can do `/SomeFamilys/Path,` or `/SomeFamilys/.cd, Path,` instead of `/SomeFamilys/Path/.cd` if you like.

**Thing 2:**

The second thingie is about filtering keys. I.e., the second thingie is about the possibility of selecting which ⟨keys⟩ and/or ⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs of a given comma-separated list of ⟨keys⟩ and ⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs to carry out.

This can be handy, e.g., with a routine where the user shall provide a comma-separated list of ⟨keys⟩ and ⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs only in one place, but not all ⟨keys⟩/⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs shall be carried out in the same stage of the processing of that routine, but some of the ⟨keys⟩/⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs provided by the user shall be carried out in earlier stages of processing than others, so that in any case the carrying out of more than one instance of a macro for processing ⟨keys⟩/⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs is to take place in the course of carrying out that routine.

Usually one uses one of the macros `\pgfkeys` or `\pgfqkeys` for specifying within its argument a comma-separated list of ⟨keys⟩ and ⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs. The ⟨keys⟩ and ⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs of the list are carried out one by one.

But there are also the macros `\pgfkeysfiltered` and `\pgfqkeysfiltered`. These macros also process a comma-separated list of ⟨keys⟩ and ⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs. But they do not carry out each of the ⟨keys⟩/⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs. They carry out only those of them where the ⟨key⟩ matches some key-filtering-criteria.

So the question arises what key-filtering-criteria?

You can adjust the key-filtering-criteria for the macros `\pgfkeysfiltered` and `\pgfqkeysfiltered` via the macro `\pgfkeys`. There are various key-filters. Those provided by the package **pgfkeys** are in the key-path `/pgf/key filters`.  By saying `/pgf/key filters/⟨KEY-FILTER⟩/.install key filter,`, i.e., by applying the handler `/.install key filter` to the key `/pgf/key filters/⟨KEY-FILTER⟩` within the argument of the macro `\pgfkeys` you "tell" the system that henceforth instances of the macros `\pgfkeysfiltered` and `\pgfqkeysfiltered` shall apply the key-filter `/pgf/key filters/⟨KEY-FILTER⟩`.

One of the key-filters is the key-filter `/pgf/key filters/active families`. If via giving the directive `/pgf/key filters/active families/.install key filter` within the argument of the macro `\pgfkeys` you provide the instruction that subsequent instances of `\pgfkeysfiltered` and `\pgfqkeysfiltered` shall use that key-filter, then with subsequent instances of the macros `\pgfkeysfiltered` and `\pgfqkeysfiltered` only such ⟨keys⟩ and ⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs of the comma-separated list are carried out that belong to a key-family which currently is activated.

This in turn means that somehow it must be specified what key-families exist, what keys belong to them and which existing key-familys have the property of being active. This in turn is also done in the argument of `\pgfkeys`, via the handlers `/.is family`, `/.belongs to family={...}` and `/.activate family`.

So in short:

The macro `\pgfkeys{...}` can be used for configuring the behavior of subsequent instances of the macros `\pgfkeysfiltered{...}` and `\pgfqkeysfiltered{...}`.
When via `\pgfkeys` installing (better say selecting) a key-filter and configuring facilities belonging to the selected key-filter, then subsequent instances of the macros `\pgfkeysfiltered` and `\pgfqkeysfiltered` apply that key-filter, i.e., carry out only those ⟨keys⟩ or ⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs of the comma-separated list, that pass the key-filter.

Keeping processing a comma-separated list of ⟨keys⟩ or ⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs while filtering keys separate from processing a comma-separated list of  ⟨keys⟩ or ⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs while not filtering keys—the further is done via the macros `\pgfkeysfiltered`/`\pgfqkeysfiltered`, the latter is done via the macros `\pgfkeys`/`\pgfqkeys` — is needed as otherwise you might end up configuring and installing(selecting) and thus using a key-filter which laterwards prevents the applying of  ⟨keys⟩ or ⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩-pairs which serve the purpose of reconfiguring facilities of a key-filter or serve the purpose of switching to another key-filter or serve the purpose of turning off key-filtering altogether.

Probably the following example gives a clue of what the concept of key-filtering by membership of currently activated key-families is about:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%============[adjust margins/layout]============================================
\paperheight=2\paperheight
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%
\oddsidemargin=1.5cm
\marginparsep=.2\oddsidemargin
\marginparwidth=.4\oddsidemargin
\textwidth=\paperwidth
\advance\textwidth by -2\oddsidemargin
\advance\oddsidemargin by -1in
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\textheight=\paperheight
\topmargin=1.5cm
\headheight=0ex
\headsep=0ex
\advance\textheight by -2\topmargin
\advance\topmargin by -1in
{\normalfont
 \setbox\csname @tempboxa\endcsname\hbox{0123456789}%
 \global\footskip=\dimexpr .5cm -.5\dp\csname @tempboxa\endcsname
                                +.5\ht\csname @tempboxa\endcsname\relax
}%
{\normalfont
 \setbox\csname @tempboxa\endcsname\hbox{%
    0123456789ANCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%
 }%
 \global\topskip=\ht\csname @tempboxa\endcsname
}%
\pagestyle{plain}%
\parindent=0ex
%==================[eof margin-adjustments]=====================================
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item Use \verb|\pgfkeys| for introducing keys and key-families and making keys
members of key-families; also use \verb|\pgfkeys| for adjusting the behavior of
the macros \verb|\pgfkeysfiltered| and \verb|\pgfqkeysfiltered|, i.e., for
selecting the key-filter which the macros \verb|\pgfkeysfiltered|/\hskip0pt
\verb|\pgfqkeysfiltered| shall apply, and configuring facilities of that
key-filter:

\begin{verbatim}
\pgfkeys{
  %
  % Introduce keys:
  %
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyE/.code=\par\noindent KeyE of Some Familys path has value: #1,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyF/.code=\par\noindent KeyF of Some Familys path has value: #1,
  /First/Path/KeyA/.code=\par\noindent KeyA of first path has value: #1,
  /First/Path/KeyB/.code=\par\noindent KeyB of first path has value: #1,
  /Second/Path/KeyC/.code=\par\noindent KeyC of second path has value: #1,
  /Second/Path/KeyD/.code=\par\noindent KeyD of second path has value: #1,
  %
  % Introduce key-families:
  %
  /SomeFamilys/Path/.is family,
  %
  % Make keys members of key-families:
  %
  /First/Path/KeyA/.belongs to family={/SomeFamilys/Path},
  /Second/Path/KeyD/.belongs to family={/SomeFamilys/Path},
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyF/.belongs to family={/SomeFamilys/Path},
  %
  % Let's configure the key-filtering done when applying the macro
  % \pgf(q)keysfiltered:
  %
  % - Select the key-filter which filters for keys in activated key-families:
  %
  /pgf/key filters/active families/.install key filter,
  %
  % - Make the key-family /SomeFamilys/Path an activated key-family:
  %
  /SomeFamilys/Path/.activate family,
}%
\end{verbatim}
%
\pgfkeys{
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyE/.code=\par\noindent KeyE of Some Familys path has value: #1,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyF/.code=\par\noindent KeyF of Some Familys path has value: #1,
  /First/Path/KeyA/.code=\par\noindent KeyA of first path has value: #1,
  /First/Path/KeyB/.code=\par\noindent KeyB of first path has value: #1,
  /Second/Path/KeyC/.code=\par\noindent KeyC of second path has value: #1,
  /Second/Path/KeyD/.code=\par\noindent KeyD of second path has value: #1,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/.is family,
  /First/Path/KeyA/.belongs to family={/SomeFamilys/Path},
  /Second/Path/KeyD/.belongs to family={/SomeFamilys/Path},
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyF/.belongs to family={/SomeFamilys/Path},
  /pgf/key filters/active families/.install key filter,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/.activate family,
}%


\item Use \verb|\pgfkeysfiltered| where you cannot specify keys in abbreviated
form:

\begin{verbatim}
\pgfkeysfiltered{
  /First/Path/KeyA=A,
  /First/Path/KeyB=B,
  /Second/Path/KeyC=C,
  /Second/Path/KeyD=D,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyE=E,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyF=F,
}%
\end{verbatim}

\noindent Result:

\pgfkeysfiltered{
  /First/Path/KeyA=A,
  /First/Path/KeyB=B,
  /Second/Path/KeyC=C,
  /Second/Path/KeyD=D,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyE=E,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyF=F,
}%

\vskip\topsep\vskip\partopsep

\noindent As you can see, only \verb|KeyA|, \verb|KeyD| and \verb|KeyF| are
carried out as \verb|\pgf(q)keysfiltered| is configured to filter for keys in
active key-families while only the key-family \verb|/SomeFamilys/Path| is
activated to which \verb|KeyB|, \verb|KeyC| and \verb|KeyE| do not belong.\\
(With \verb|\pgf(q)keysfiltered| by design you cannot use \verb|/.cd| and
abbreviate keys because key handlers like \verb|/.cd| actually are just keys
in a specific path and thus might be filtered out instead of being applied.)

\item Use \verb|\pgfqkeysfiltered| where you can specify one key-path in the 1st
argument, whose keys may be abbreviated:\\
(This time, too, only \verb|KeyA|, \verb|KeyD| and \verb|KeyF| are carried out
as \verb|\pgf(q)keysfiltered| is still configured to filter for keys in active
key-families while only the key-family \verb|/SomeFamilys/Path| is activated
to which \verb|KeyB|, \verb|KeyC| and \verb|KeyE| do not belong.)

\begin{verbatim}
\pgfqkeysfiltered{/First/Path}{
  KeyA=A,
  KeyB=B,
  /Second/Path/KeyC=C,
  /Second/Path/KeyD=D,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyE=E,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyF=F,
}%
\end{verbatim}

\noindent Result:

\vskip\topsep\vskip\partopsep

\pgfqkeysfiltered{/First/Path}{
  KeyA=A,
  KeyB=B,
  /Second/Path/KeyC=C,
  /Second/Path/KeyD=D,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyE=E,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyF=F,
}%

\vskip\topsep\vskip\partopsep

\item Use \verb|\pgfkeys| for resetting the behavior of the macros
\verb|\pgfkeysfiltered| and \verb|\pgfqkeysfiltered|:

\begin{verbatim}
\pgfkeys{
  % Let's reset the key-filtering done when applying the macro \pgf(q)keysfiltered
  % so that with \pgf(q)keysfiltered no filtering of keys takes place:
  % - Make the key-family /SomeFamilys/Path a deactivated key-family:
  /SomeFamilys/Path/.deactivate family,
  % - Install/select the key-filter "true" which filters for every key:
  /pgf/key filters/true/.install key filter,
}%
\end{verbatim}
%
\pgfkeys{
  /SomeFamilys/Path/.deactivate family,
  /pgf/key filters/true/.install key filter,
}%

\item Use \verb|\pgfkeysfiltered| where you cannot specify keys in abbreviated
form:\\
(All keys are carried out as now \verb|\pgf(q)keysfiltered| is configured to
filter for every key.)

\begin{verbatim}
\pgfkeysfiltered{
  /First/Path/KeyA=A,
  /First/Path/KeyB=B,
  /Second/Path/KeyC=C,
  /Second/Path/KeyD=D,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyE=E,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyF=F,
}%
\end{verbatim}

\noindent Result:

\vskip\topsep\vskip\partopsep

\pgfkeysfiltered{
  /First/Path/KeyA=A,
  /First/Path/KeyB=B,
  /Second/Path/KeyC=C,
  /Second/Path/KeyD=D,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyE=E,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyF=F,
}%

\item Use \verb|\pgfqkeysfiltered| where you can specify one key-path in the 1st
argument whose keys may be abbreviated:\\
(All keys are carried out as now \verb|\pgf(q)keysfiltered| is configured to
filter for every key.)

\begin{verbatim}
\pgfqkeysfiltered{/First/Path}{
  KeyA=A,
  KeyB=B,
  /Second/Path/KeyC=C,
  /Second/Path/KeyD=D,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyE=E,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyF=F,
}%
\end{verbatim}

\noindent Result:

\vskip\topsep\vskip\partopsep

\pgfqkeysfiltered{/First/Path}{
  KeyA=A,
  KeyB=B,
  /Second/Path/KeyC=C,
  /Second/Path/KeyD=D,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyE=E,
  /SomeFamilys/Path/KeyF=F,
}%

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `.is family` allows to use the path you specified it for to act as a `.cd` without you actually using the `.cd`-handler explicitly.

And that's about all the magic (at least in most cases, see [Ulrich Diez's very detailed and nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709845/117050) for the other cases). Yes, you can still use `.cd` explicitly, the handler doesn't cease to work:

```
\RequirePackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{/foo/.is family, /foo/bar/.code=\typeout{bar used with #1}}

\pgfkeys{/foo/.cd, bar=baz}

\stop
```

prints

```
bar used with baz
```

But for package options with `pgfopts` you don't need either of the two:

```
\pgfqkeys{/mypackage}{<key definitions>}
\ProcessPgfOptions{/mypackage}
```

(`\pgfqkeys{/path}` is the same as `\pgfkeys{/path/.cd}` but faster and should be preferred in package code)

That being said, I'd still recommend you for any new packages to use either LaTeX's new built in mechanism for package options (`\DeclareKeys{<key definitions>}` and then `\ProcessKeyOptions`), or use `expkv-opt` (*disclaimer:* of which I'm the author). If you want to interface with KOMA another solution might be the option handling provided by `scrbase` that also uses the new option handling mechanism of LaTeX (though I'm not sure of the exact feature range provided by it).