# Moving from pgfkeys to latex3 key-val system to handle package options

Tags: latex3, programming, pgfkeys, package-writing, key-value

I have been advised in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/709766/17200) to move from `pgfopts` to `latex3` to handle package options. I would like to do that but I must admit that I am a little lost. Examples with the patterns I'm using the most would tremendously help me.

**QUESTION:** How to replace the `pgfopts` package option management system of `mypackage` below by `latex3` key-value system? If you see things in this package which could be improved, then an answer in two steps would be great:

1. the most literal translation possible from `pgfopts` to `latex3`
2. possible improvements of the resulting updated package

---

**mypackage.sty**

```
% preamble
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2024/01/01 MyPackage]
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\makeatletter

% package options
\pgfkeys{
    /mypackage/.is family,
    /mypackage/.cd,
    % options
    option/.store in = \mypackage@option,
    option = a,
    eoption/.estore in = \mypackage@eoption,
    eoption = b,
    % color
    color/.estore in = \mypackage@color,
    color = ,
    blue/.code = \pgfkeys{/mypackage/color = blue},
    blue/.value forbidden,
    red/.code = \pgfkeys{/mypackage/color = red},
    red/.value forbidden,
    green/.code = \pgfkeys{/mypackage/color = green},
    green/.value forbidden,
    % choice
    choice/.is choice,
    choice/.estore in = \mypackage@choice,
    choice/true/.code = \pgfkeys{/mypackage/choice = true},
    choice/false/.code = \pgfkeys{/mypackage/choice = false},
    choice/.default = true,
    choice = false,
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/mypackage}

% \print{identifier}: print current mypackage options
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\print}{m}{
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\texttt{mypackage}\ options:\ \texttt{#1}}\\
    \hline
    option & \mypackage@option \\
    eoption & \mypackage@eoption \\
    color & \mypackage@color \\
    choice & \mypackage@choice \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}\par\bigskip
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% \setup{package}{option = xxxx}: set options for the specified package
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setup}{mm}{\mypackage_setup:en{#1}{#2}}
\cs_new:Nn \mypackage_setup:nn{\pgfkeys{/#1,#2}}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mypackage_setup:nn{en}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% \reset{package}: reset options to default for the specified package
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\reset}{m}{\mypackage_reset:e{#1}}
\cs_new:Nn \mypackage_reset:n{\setup{#1}{#1@initial}}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mypackage_reset:n{e}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% \newstyle(*expanded){package}{style}{options}: create a style for the package
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newstyle}{smmm}{\mypackage_newstyle:neen{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\cs_new:Nn \mypackage_newstyle:nnnn{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
        \setup{#2}{#2@#3/.style/.expanded={#4}}
    }{
        \setup{#2}{#2@#3/.style={#4}}
    }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mypackage_newstyle:nnnn{neen}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% \setstyle{package}{style}: set the provided style for the given package
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setstyle}{mm}{\mypackage_setstyle:ee{#1}{#2}}
\cs_new:Nn \mypackage_setstyle:nn{\setup{#1}{#1@#2}}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mypackage_setstyle:nn{ee}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% initial style
\newstyle*{mypackage}{initial}{
    option = \mypackage@option,
    eoption = \mypackage@eoption,
    color = \mypackage@color,
    choice = \mypackage@choice,
}

% closing
\makeatother
```

---

**mydocument.tex**

```
\documentclass[varwidth = true]{standalone}
\usepackage[blue]{mypackage}

\newstyle{mypackage}{mystyle}{option = A, eoption = B, green, choice = false}

\begin{document}
\print{1}
\setup{mypackage}{red}
\print{2}
\setup{mypackage}{choice}
\print{3}
\reset{mypackage}
\print{4}
\begingroup
\setup{mypackage}{option = X, eoption = Y}
\print{5}
\endgroup
\print{6}
\setstyle{mypackage}{mystyle}
\print{7}
\end{document}
```

---

**output**

[image: output]

Comment: Inside a package loaded with either `\RequirePackage` or `\usepackage` you don't have to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, that's better handled by the LaTeX kernel instead, you should remove them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, in `l3keys`/`ltkeys` setting keys and defining keys are two separated things, so the way you define new styles needs a bit of change. The fact that you're defining your `\setup` in a way that it might be used to set arbitrary package's keys is weird or at least unusual, and not necessary with `ltkeys` because `\SetKeys` already allows that via its optional argument. Same is true for your styles, it's weird that you allow arbitrary injections here, imho, you should limit that to your own package's namespace.

Nevertheless, this is more or less a direct copy of your code just to make it work with `ltkeys` instead of `pgfkeys`, no further improvements whatsoever (those are further down this answer). Note that not all the handlers you need are available from the `ltkeys` layer, and you have to use the `l3keys` names for them. I'd suggest you change your entire package to `expl3` instead of using this strange mix of L3 and L2e code.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.sty}
% preamble
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{\@currname}[2024/01/01 MyPackage]
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareKeys
  {
    % options
     option  .store      = \mypackage@option
    ,option  .initial:n  = a
    ,eoption .tl_set_e:c = mypackage@eoption
    ,eoption .initial:n  = b
    % colors
    ,color   .tl_set_e:c = mypackage@color
    ,blue    .meta:n     = { color = blue }
    ,blue    .value_forbidden:n = true
    ,red     .meta:n     = { color = red }
    ,red     .value_forbidden:n = true
    ,green   .meta:n     = { color = green }
    ,green   .value_forbidden:n = true
    % choice
    ,choice  .choices:nn = { true, false }
      { \cs_set_eq:NN \mypackage@choice \l_keys_choice_tl }
    ,choice  .default:n  = true
    ,choice  .initial:n  = false
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\ProcessKeyOptions

% \print{identifier}: print current mypackage options
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\print}{m}{
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\texttt{mypackage}\ options:\ \texttt{#1}}\\
    \hline
    option & \mypackage@option \\
    eoption & \mypackage@eoption \\
    color & \mypackage@color \\
    choice & \mypackage@choice \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}\par\bigskip
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% \setup{package}{option = xxxx}: set options for the specified package
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setup}{mm}{\mypackage_setup:en{#1}{#2}}
\cs_new:Nn \mypackage_setup:nn{\SetKeys[#1]{#2}}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mypackage_setup:nn{en}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% \reset{package}: reset options to default for the specified package
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\reset}{m}{\mypackage_reset:e{#1}}
\cs_new:Nn \mypackage_reset:n{\setup{#1}{#1@initial}}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mypackage_reset:n{e}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% \newstyle(*expanded){package}{style}{options}: create a style for the package
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newstyle}{smmm}{\mypackage_newstyle:neen{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\cs_new:Nn \mypackage_newstyle:nnnn{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
      \keys_define:ne {#2} { \exp_not:n { #2@#3 } .meta:n = {#4} }
    }{
      \keys_define:nn {#2} { #2@#3 .meta:n = {#4} }
    }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mypackage_newstyle:nnnn{neen}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% \setstyle{package}{style}: set the provided style for the given package
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setstyle}{mm}{\mypackage_setstyle:ee{#1}{#2}}
\cs_new:Nn \mypackage_setstyle:nn{\setup{#1}{#1@#2}}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mypackage_setstyle:nn{ee}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% initial style
\newstyle*{\@currname}{initial}{
    option = \mypackage@option,
    eoption = \mypackage@eoption,
    color = \mypackage@color,
    choice = \mypackage@choice,
}
% closing
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[varwidth = true]{standalone}
\usepackage[blue]{\jobname}

\newstyle{\jobname}{mystyle}{option = A, eoption = B, green, choice = false}

\begin{document}
\print{1}
\setup{\jobname}{red}
\print{2}
\setup{\jobname}{choice}
\print{3}
\reset{\jobname}
\print{4}
\begingroup
\setup{\jobname}{option = X, eoption = Y}
\print{5}
\endgroup
\print{6}
\setstyle{\jobname}{mystyle}
\print{7}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is a version of your code that has a few changes that I'd make (and hinted at above already):

- only provide direct interfaces for your own package
- move to L3 code where possible
- in `\newstyle` actually make sure it is a new style
- don't over-expand for the `reset`-list (use `\exp_not:V`)
- set a much closer to reality minimum date for the used LaTeX kernel
- define macros that should be protected as protected

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.sty}
% not entirely sure this is absolutely correct, but it's a much better guess
% than 1994 (2022/06/01 it is at least due to `\keys_precompile:nnN`)
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2022/06/01]
\ProvidesExplPackage{\@currname}{2024-01-01}{0.0}{MyPackage}

\keys_define:nn { mypackage }
  {
    % options
     option  .tl_set:N   = \l_mypackage_option_tl
    ,option  .initial:n  = a
    ,eoption .tl_set_e:N = \l_mypackage_eoption_tl
    ,eoption .initial:n  = b
    % colors
    ,color   .tl_set_e:N = \l_mypackage_color_tl
    % empty initial value is implicitly set if the tl doesn't exist yet
    ,blue    .meta:n     = { color = blue }
    ,blue    .value_forbidden:n = true
    ,red     .meta:n     = { color = red }
    ,red     .value_forbidden:n = true
    ,green   .meta:n     = { color = green }
    ,green   .value_forbidden:n = true
    % choice
    ,choice  .choices:nn = { true, false }
      { \tl_set_eq:NN \l_mypackage_choice_tl \l_keys_choice_tl }
    ,choice  .default:n  = true
    ,choice  .initial:n  = false
  }
\ProcessKeyOptions[mypackage]

% \print{identifier}: print current mypackage options
\NewDocumentCommand{\print}{m}{
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\texttt{mypackage}~ options:~ \texttt{#1}} \\
    \hline
    option  & \l_mypackage_option_tl  \\
    eoption & \l_mypackage_eoption_tl \\
    color   & \l_mypackage_color_tl   \\
    choice  & \l_mypackage_choice_tl  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}\par\bigskip
}

% \mypackagesetup{option = xxxx}: set options for mypackage
\NewDocumentCommand \mypackagesetup { m }
  { \keys_set:nn { mypackage } {#1} }

% \newstyle(*expanded){style}{options}: create a style for the package
\NewDocumentCommand \newstyle { smm }
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      { \mypackage_newstyle:ee {#2} {#3} }
      { \mypackage_newstyle:en {#2} {#3} }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mypackage_newstyle:nn #1#2
  {
    \keys_if_exist:nnTF { mypackage } { mypackage@#1 }
      { \msg_error:nnn  { mypackage } { style-exists } {#1} }
      { \keys_define:nn { mypackage } { mypackage@#1 .meta:n = {#2} } }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { mypackage } { style-exists }
  { The~ style~ `#1'~ already~ exists.~ Ignoring~ new~ definition. }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mypackage_newstyle:nn { en, ee }

% \setstyle{style}: set the provided style for the given package
\NewDocumentCommand \setstyle { m } { \mypackage_setstyle:e {#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mypackage_setstyle:n #1
  { \keys_set:nn { mypackage } { mypackage@#1 } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mypackage_setstyle:n { e }

% \mypackagereset: reset options to default
% initial style (speed optimised, this isn't done via key=value at use time)
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_precompile:nnN { ne }
\keys_precompile:neN { mypackage }
  {
     option  = \exp_not:V \l_mypackage_option_tl
    ,eoption = \exp_not:V \l_mypackage_eoption_tl
    ,color   = \exp_not:V \l_mypackage_color_tl
    ,choice  = \exp_not:V \l_mypackage_choice_tl
  }
  \l_tmpa_tl
\exp_args:NNnV \NewDocumentCommand \mypackagereset {} \l_tmpa_tl
% closing
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[varwidth = true]{standalone}
\usepackage[blue]{\jobname}

\newstyle{mystyle}{option = A, eoption = B, green, choice = false}

\begin{document}
\print{1}
\mypackagesetup{red}
\print{2}
\mypackagesetup{choice}
\print{3}
\mypackagereset
\print{4}
\begingroup
\mypackagesetup{option = X, eoption = Y}
\print{5}
\endgroup
\print{6}
\setstyle{mystyle}
\print{7}
\end{document}
```

---

The following is a big list of all the key-handlers in `pgfkeys` (as described in `pgfmanual` section 87.4 for version 3.1.10) and their counterparts in `l3keys` and the `ltkeys`-layer (which is much smaller as you can see, but inside `\DeclareKeys` you can use all the handlers from the `l3keys` column as well). Additionally I included a column with `expkv-def` types (because I'm the author of `expkv` and this is a shameless advertisement).

Keep in mind that `l3keys` is inspired by `pgfkeys`, but has a few very different design choices (separation of defining and setting for instance), hence the list looks rather sparse. But there are quite some handlers defined in `l3keys` missing in this table as they don't have a counterpart in `pgfkeys`.

| `pgfkeys` | `l3keys` | `ltkeys` | `expkv-def` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `.cd` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.is family` | N/A<sup>l1</sup> | N/A | N/A<sup>e1</sup> |
| `.default` | `.default:n` | N/A | `default` |
| `.value required` | `.value_required:n = true` | N/A | built in<sup>e2</sup> |
| `.value forbidden` | `.value_forbidden:n = true` | N/A | built in<sup>e2</sup> |
| `.code` | `.code:n` | `.code` | `code`/`noval` |
| `.ecode` | N/A | N/A | `ecode`/`enoval` |
| `.code 2 args` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.ecode 2 args` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.code n args` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.ecode n args` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.code args` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.ecode args` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.add code` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.prefix code` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.append code` | N/A | N/A | `also code`/`also noval` |
| `.style` | `.meta:n` | N/A | `meta`/`nmeta` |
| `.estyle` | N/A | N/A | `exp`-notation + `meta` |
| `.style 2 args` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.estyle 2 args` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.style n args` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.add style` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.style args` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.estyle args` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.prefix style` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.append style` | N/A | N/A | `also meta` |
| `.initial` | N/A<sup>l2</sup> | N/A | N/A<sup>e3</sup> |
| `.get` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.add` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.prefix` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.append` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.link` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.store in` | `.tl_set:N` | `.store` | `store` |
| `.estore in` | `.tl_set_e:N` | N/A | `estore` |
| `.is if` | `.legacy_if_set:n` | `.if` | `bool` |
| `.is choice` | `.choice:`/`.choices:nn` | N/A | `choice` |
| `.expand once` | N/A | N/A | `exp`-notation |
| `.expand twice` | N/A | N/A | `exp`-notation |
| `.expanded` | N/A | N/A | `exp`-notation |
| `.evaluated` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.list` | N/A<sup>l3</sup> | N/A | N/A |
| `.forward to` | N/A | N/A | `also meta` |
| `.search also` | N/A | N/A | `unknown redirect` |
| `.try` | N/A<sup>l4</sup> | N/A | N/A<sup>e4</sup> |
| `.retry` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.lastretry` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.show value` | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| `.show code` | N/A | N/A | N/A |

<sup>l1</sup>
key filtering is possible with `.groups:n`, the `.cd`-part
of the functionality isn't supported.

<sup>l2</sup>
the `.initial:n` provided by `l3keys` isn't comparible,
that one is used to set a value (since defining and setting keys is decoupled).

<sup>l3</sup>
for choice like keys there is
`.multichoice:`/`.multichoices:nn`.

<sup>l4</sup>
You can check for key existance with `\keys_if_exists:nnTF` but there
is no `.try` like handler to that. Additionally you can use
`\keys_set_known:nnN` to only set known keys (like `.try`
on all keys at once).

<sup>e1</sup>
the `.cd` part is possible with `set`, there is no key
filtering built into `expkv`, only sets.

<sup>e2</sup>
built in behaviour because `expkv` differentiates between keys
taking a value and those without (and both might share the same user-level
name).

<sup>e3</sup>
just like `l3keys`, defining and setting keys is decoupled, the
`initial` type sets a value and isn't comparable to
`.initial` of `pgfkeys`.

<sup>e4</sup>
You can check for key existance with `\ekvifdefined` and
`\ekvifdefinedNoVal`, but there is no `.try` like handler
at use time.

Comment: So essentially the `\setstyle`  is congruent with PGF's  `.style` sort of?

Comment: @yannisl inside `\DeclareKeys`/`\keys_define:nn` a `.meta:n` is congruent to a PGF `.style`, the `\newstyle` is a wrapper around that, `\setstyle` is just the interface to that mechanism as given in the OP. I'd honestly not set a `mypackage@`-prefix for those styles such that they can be used directly inside a key=value list, but that's the given interface.

Comment: A huge difference btween PGF and l3keys is that with PGF one can define new handlers, so for example I have a `.bool` defined that uses l3 bool. Or a `.fontsize` that can accept values and store them in a tl. Such code can be defined once and extends the range of available handlers.  Also the fact that with PGF spaces are significant or not significant as you wish. But perhaps I will post a series of questions over the next few days so one can compare with concrete examples.

Comment: Your package looks promising, needs a bit of improvement of the manual with some examples comparing l3keys to it, maybe they are there but I missed them.

Comment: @yannisl you can also use spaces in `l3keys` key-names (`\keys_define:nn { mypkg } { my~ key .tl_set:N = \l_mypkg_mykey_tl } \set_keys:nn { mypkg } { my~ key = foo }` works fine). The extensibility is a point for `pgfkeys`, yes, though this isn't added to `l3keys` by design. If you really need something like that you ought to define an auxiliary function and use `.code:n`.

Comment: @yannisl if you find shortcomings in the documentation I'd be more than happy to get a bug ticket opened so we can discuss them and I can work on them. Or even PRs. If you don't have the necessary account you can also send me these per mail. Though the manual does no direct comparison with other packages to document features in general currently, only the very brief comparisons in the last section.

Comment: @Skillmon: I am not sure to understand the advantages of using `\keys_define:nn` vs `\DeclareKeys` as in your "improved" version of the code. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Vincent there are two reasons: `\keys_define:nn` is marginally faster, because it doesn't have to search for an optional argument. And for more uniform code, every function that exists as an L3-variant is used as such.